# How to parseInt captured block in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to increase digit right after '#'.
My function:

```js
let test = `#2*345+#1-#2-3+#1`;
console.log(test.replace(/#([0-9])/g, `#${'$1' + 1}`)); //#21*345+#11-#21-3
console.log(test.replace(/#([0-9])/g, `#${parseInt('$1') + 1}`)); //#NaN*345+#NaN-#NaN-3

//but my expect result is "#3*345+#2-#3-3"
```

Hope your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group substitution occurs *after* the template literal is evaluated. Use a replacer function instead:

```js
let test = `#2*345+#1-#2-3+#1`;
console.log(test.replace(/#([0-9])/g, (_, num) => `#${parseInt(num) + 1}`));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use callback function of replace

```js
let test = `#2*345+#1-#2-3+#1`;

let op = test.replace(/#([0-9])/g, (match,g1)=>`#${parseInt(g1) + 1}`);

console.log(op)
```